# Can we do fade in and fade out in iframes

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to make fade in and fade out transitions in iframes?

Answer (score 9):

Fading in or out can be achieved by changing the opacity of an element over time, a very simple example:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');

fadeOut(iframe, 1000);

function fadeOut(el, duration) {

    /*
     * @param el - The element to be faded out.
     * @param duration - Animation duration in milliseconds.
     */

    var step = 10 / duration,
        opacity = 1;
    function next() {
        if (opacity <= 0) { return; }
        el.style.opacity = ( opacity -= step );
        setTimeout(next, 10);
    }
    next();
}
```

---

While jQuery is an incredible library your usage of it should be justified by more than just its ability to create fancy effects. A library should be adopted for its completeness and ease of use; not because it happens to offer just *one* thing you might want to use.

Comment: +1 Very beautiful script! Nice & concise! I'm gonna end up not using jQuery after all. One caveat: `arguments.callee` has been deprecated in javascript so a named function would be best. (I edited your answer accordingly) Thanks again!

Comment: `if (opacity <= 0) { el.style.opacity = 0; return; }` else you may end up with opacity just above 0.0

Answer (score 4):

you can do it with jquery!

http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeOut

http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeIn

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe, you can let CSS handle this for you. With a very little of javascript to trigger the effect.

**CSS:**

```css
#iframe_selector {
  /* initial values for iframe, we'll change them via javascript. */
  opacity: 0;
  /* Note: In out/2016 opacity is on 97.39% of browsers */
  /* Just an extra property to show multiple transitions, not needed for fade effect. */
  height: 0;
  /* Here you can handle a couple of transitions as you wish */
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out, height 3s ease-in-out;
  /* Note: Add all prefixes */
}
```

**Javascript**

```js
function toogleIframe(iframe) {
  //Check if is show with opacity property,
  if (iframe.style.opacity == 0) {
    //and set to original values,
    iframe.style.opacity = 1;
    iframe.style.height = '500px';
  } else {
    //or hide it.
    iframe.style.opacity = 0;
    iframe.style.height = '0px';
  }
}

//And now, just use it...
//Examples:
domReady(function() {
  toogleIframe(document.getElementById('iframe_selector'));
});

var button = document.getElementById('my_button');
button.onclick = function() {
  toogleIframe(document.getElementById('iframe_selector'));
};

//Just specify when your iframe needs to be show or not...
```

Just one thing, maybe you want load your iframe just when it is going to show, to do this just remove `src` from your iframe in HTML, and add in javascript with `iframe.src`. That was my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onload property and a css animation to make the iframe fade in once loaded

```
<iframe
    src="..."
    onload="this.style.opacity = '1';"
    style="
        opacity: 0;
        transition-duration: 300ms;
        transition-property: opacity;
        transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    "
></iframe>
```