# How to use `arrive.js` to find an element arrived inside of a `iFrame'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I require to find the DOM element which is adding inside of a iframe, with the iframe added. for determine to find the element added, I am using this plugin

all i doing from **chrome ext.**

[arrive.js](https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive/)
`body>iframe1>iframe.ssueContentIframe2>#SmartReportTabContent1>loopElements>link`

like this:

```
document.arrive(".ssueContentIframe", function() {
    console.log('.ssueContentIframe arrived', this);//works

this.arrive('#SmartReportTabContent1', function(){
console.log('arrive 2');//not working
});
});
```

what is wrong here? any one help me please?

Answer (score 2):

To check for an element within an iframe you need to include the [arrive.js](https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive) library and your script that calls the `arrive()` function within the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to [detect whether iframe is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267010/how-can-i-detect-whether-an-iframe-is-loaded) there's other solutions, but if you want to [muck around in the iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945340/how-to-access-an-iframe-and-affect-it-with-jquery) you have to keep in mind cross-domain policies.

> Javascript has a Same-Origin policy in which javascript on the outer page cannot access the contentWindow or DOM (or global state) of the iframe page if it does not share the Same-Origin
>   -- [T. Stone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8945727/2848941)

Seems to me arrive.js isn't the problem, it's trying to mess with an iframe.