# Embed (iframe or object) and Modify (jQuery) webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm simply trying to load another webpage in my webpage using the object tag or iframe. Then, I would like to remove some element of the loaded page with jQuery.

Here is my code

```
<div> 
    <object type="text/html" data="http://ebird.org/ebird/map/eurtre1" width="100%" height="400px" id="eurtre1">
    </object>
 </div>

<script>
jQuery( window ).load(function() {
    jQuery('#map-sidebar').remove();
});
</script>
```

And, as you guess, it is not working... 
I have tried:

```
jQuery('#eurtre1').contents().find('#map-sidebar')
```

and

```
jQuery('#eurtre1')[0].contentDocument.children
```

The wired thing is that on my browser, I can do it in the console, once I've selected the inside of the object...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to a similar question:

[how to access an iframe and affect it with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945340/how-to-access-an-iframe-and-affect-it-with-jquery)

Basically you can't due to Javascript same-origin policy but if you have access to the loaded content in the iframe you could use `window.postMessage`

You could also add a parameter to the iframe's src tag to post a message, something like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com?hideElement=true"></iframe>
```

Again you will have to have access the content of the iframe to check the param and execute your code.